How to migrate Vaadin 8 textField.setValue("Value", true) to vaadin 14?
In Vaadin 8 textfield setValue, there is an option that allows users to set if it is originated from user or not.
For example:
textField.setValue("Value", true);
In Vaadin 14, there is no parameter to set origination. How can we migrate this?
Thanks in advance.
Try to extend text field to add a property originated, but this is not convenient.

In case this is an X-Y-problem: would you mind also adding, why you need this? Do you need to "fake" user input, because later value change listeners look for "fromClient" or is this used inside a composite field?

There is no way to programmatically set the value while making it believe the valuechange originates from the user. When using textField.setValue("abc") then the valueChange is always assumed to originate from code. And to me, that makes total sense.
I don't know what you tried to achieve with this, but there must be another way to do so. If you show your vaadin-8 code I'm happy to try to help find a better solution that works in vaadin-14

The method in Vaadin 8 is protected API, which indicates it's not meant for public use. The functionality has been moved to be inside the private final AbstractFieldSupport<C, T> fieldSupport; member of AbstractField to make sure it won't be used the way you're using it. You should find another way to achieve the effect you're going for, as it's not intended that you should be able to indicate an event is from the client even if it's not.
